# Entity Framework Core Conexión y cargar datos a una GridView. ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Estoy tratando de conectar una `GridView` con `Entity Framework Core` pero no me muestra error en el `DataBind` probé añadiéndole un `.ToList()` pero observo que no me carga el data cuando le agrego este.
Lo que tengo de código es esto:

```
    public partial class PAGE1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Contexto db = new Contexto();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = db.InfoUsuario;
        GridUsuario.DataSource = data.ToList();
        GridUsuario.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo iniciar el context dentro del método `Page_Load`.

Comment: si defines una linea como ser var data = db.InfoUsuario.ToList(); y pones un breakpoint en el codigo puedes evaluar que hay datos en la variable?

Comment: la tabla en la db tiene registros? porque sino haya datos en la db no traera nada para visualizar